# Apply CSS rule to multiple elements within a sub-class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="class-XXX">
  <div class="class-5">
    <!-- could be any text element -->
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

For simplicity, lets assume that `class-XXX` can only have the values `class-1`, `class-2`, `class-3` and `class-4`.
I want to apply the rule `color: #fff;` to every child of `class-5` that is not a child of `class-1`. Here that part of my stylesheet:

```
.class-2 .class-5,
.class-3 .class-5,
.class-4 .class-5 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

This is not working and I'm not really sure why. I don't believe that the rule is being overridden either.

**UPDATE**

As AndrewBone pointed out, the rule appears to work in a minimal example. I now understand what is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it:

There is a rule being applied to `h1` in another CSS file (can't be removed) and that rule is being given higher priority than the rule I was writing. How can I fix this?

Here is [an example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0bomq0j/).

**SOLUTION**

Vucko pointed out that the `h1` type selector has higher priority and so the rule will not be applied. So, in order to avoid listing all possible combinations one should use the `*` selector!

End result:

```
.class-2 .class-5 *,
.class-3 .class-5 *,
.class-4 .class-5 *{
  color: #fff;
}
```

My thanks to Paulie_D and David Wilkinson for teaching me about the `:not` pseudo-selector.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/xxt2hytg/ is this not the desired result?

Comment: You could also use`:not` selector but it is a tricky selector. Is the `div` with `.class-xxx` a direct child of `body`? Or does it have any wrapper around it? *Note:* Your selector should work depending on properties (for example, `color` should not have a problem because children will inherit it from parent), the `:not` will help you achieve it with lesser code.

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/xxt2hytg/3/

Comment: @AndrewBone yes, so it would seem my rule is well formed. However, I cannot achieve my desired result. I will update the post with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some container for those `divs`, you can then use the `:not` selector (as Harry mentioned in the comment):

```css
.main :not(.class-1) .class-5 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="class-1">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-2">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-3">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-4">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-5">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>5</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.main :not(.class-1) .class-5 {
  color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d09asch7/)

Comment: The styles for `h1` override those other styles. [Here's more about CSS selector specificity (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: I want to apply this rule to `h1`, `h2`, ... , `p`, etc.. Would this be a good excuse to use `!important` or is there a cleaner way than listing all possible combinations?

Comment: Wow. I didn't knew you could use `*` as a wildcard in CSS. Very well played Vucko!

Comment: Be careful when using `*`, it can cause a lot of problems :) Also, [check this CSS Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/). And also, [:not](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) has good browser support (gte IE9).

Comment: I believe it fits in this example. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

This would do it..

```
  [class^="class-"]:not(.class-1) .class-5 {
          */ your styles here */
        }
```

...but this only works for a specific methodolody in classnames as above.

```css
[class^="class-"]:not(.class-1) .class-5 {

  color: red;

}
```

```html
<div class="class-1">
  <div class="class-5">
    <!-- could be any text element -->
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class-2">
  <div class="class-5">
    <!-- could be any text element -->
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class-3">
  <div class="class-5">
    <!-- could be any text element -->
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class-4">
  <div class="class-5">
    <!-- could be any text element -->
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="class-5">
  <div class="class-5">
    <!-- could be any text element -->
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't checked but if there is a higher level wrapper with class-0 then it will apply to all the elements because class-0 is of the required format and class-5 will be a descendant.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the part `[class^="class"]` does?

Comment: It's an attribute selector for classes that start with "class-"

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/023rox1k/

CSS:

```
.wrapper :not(.class-1) .class-5 {
  color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="class-1">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-2">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-3">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-4">
    <div class="class-5">
      <!-- could be any text element -->
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `:not` selector is quite powerful and obviously targets elements not of a certain class in this case.

Comment: Very elegant solution. But what about performance? Does `:not` (or pseudo-selectors in general) have performance overheads?

Comment: I'm not sure about :not specifically, but here's a good resource on CSS overheads and performance: [https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/](https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very useful! :)